# vs [mpk5 weaponAttachments]

Tags: iphone

I'm able to make the method for the call `[self weaponAttachments:mpk5]` but I don't like having to call `self`. I think `[mpk5 weaponAttachments]` is more natural and is easier to read.

The problem I'm having is I need to pass in the weapon (mpk5) in order to use it, which I can do with the first method but not with the second one. Does this mean that I need to subclass NSDictionary in order to be able to use a statement like `[mpk5 weaponAttachments]`? If so, how do I get ahold of the caller "mpk5" so that I can use it inside the method?

**EDIT**

I apologize for not putting this in the first time but my objective is to have [mpk5 weaponAttachments] return an NSDictionary or NSArray. Right now I have NSDictionary *attachments = [self weaponAttachments:mpk5]; which works but it just doesn't seem like the best approach.

Comment: I wish my projects had function names this neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly, your two calls are a little mixed up:

`[self weaponAttachments:mpk5]` calls the `weaponAttachments` ***method***, passing in the variable `mpk5`.

But `[mpk5 weaponAttachments]` is either asking the `mpk5` ***object*** to return the `weaponAttachments` property *or* is asking the `mpk5` object to run a method called `weaponAttachments` (I'm simplifying here - it's always a method, but if you're using properties you probably won't realise this as Objective-C will create them for you).

These are fundamentally different things.

On to the brunt of your question:

> I don't like having to call `self`

...unfortunately, if you're working in an object-oriented language you're going to have to get used to this. Say I have a class called `mySimpleClass`, and a method inside that class called `doSomething`. Writing this:

`[mySimpleClass doSomething]` would be what we call a *static method*. Whereas calling `[self doSomething]` from within an instance of `mySimpleClass` would be an *instance method*.

If you're unsure of the difference between static and instance methods you should probably step back and take a look at some of the basic guides out there.

Comment: Class names should be capitalized.  Objective-C does not have static methods, it has class methods.

Comment: I edited the original post which states I would like the call to return an NSDictionary or NSArray. Also, mpk5 is a dictionary so I'm sending a dictionary the message weaponAttachments which would return a dictionary or array.